# history of religion in America

Tags: colonial-america, religious-history

What was religion of native America, before British colonial? Around when Christianity evolves in America?

Comment: You might need to narrow this down a bit. A *brief* history of religion in America could fill volumes.

Comment: I think the parenthetical part now keeps it from being too broad. But is this the question Santanu wanted answered? In the original it almost looked like it might be asking about the religion(s) of the Native Americans.

Comment: Yeah T.E.D.. I only wanted to ask about native religion in America(before British colonial America). But I was not allowed to ask a one line question, so I had to add a little more lines and the rest you know.

Comment: @Santanu Debnath You can still edit the question yourself to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Please edit the question.  On the other hand, I don't believe there was a single religion among the Native Americans if that is what you are asking - there were hundreds of tribes and dozens of nations and there was no single religion.  This question may benefit from some preliminary research.

Comment: This looks like a homework question asking for someone else to do the work.

Comment: I always wonder are there really a rich history of America!

Comment: Your question explicitly asks about Christianity. But your comment indicates your interest in *native* religion in America. That's two very different things. Unless you edit your question to make it clearer what it is you are actually asking about... well, it's unclear what you're asking. ;-)

Comment: Your edit makes it clear what you're asking about, which, however, [is answered by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_American_religion) (actually *including* the question about Christianity, right there in the article). I.e., now your question is clear, it's off-topic for history.SE. Sorry. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar - Pretty much **all** of the practices described in that webpage were reactions to European colonialism, rather than indigenous practices. That might be what the OP wanted. However, my answer assumed not.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Duly noted and upvoted.

Answer (score 7):

The Native Americans were organized into hundreds of different tribes and kingdoms, many of which were completely unrelated to each other. There was no single overreaching religion. What a Sioux believed would have been very different from an Inuit, which in turn would have been completely different than an Aztec. So there was no single big religion.

For example, [Inuit had gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit_religion) related to their game animals (they are primarily hunters). They also believed in souls which persist after death, even in their game animals.

The Siouxan peoples (farmers who supplemented with hunting) instead believed in a [single unified spirit](http://www.native-languages.org/morelegends/wakonda.htm) inherent in everything, even inanimate objects like rocks. The best way of thinking of it is similar to The Force in Star Wars. The name varies a smidge by language, but its usually something similar to "Wakonda". I believe the technical word for this kind of belief system is [Pantheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism).

The Aztecs had a proper [polytheistic pantheon.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_religion#Pantheon)

That being said, Pantheisim was fairly widespread, just not universal. Instead of "Wakonda", the Algonquins called it "[Kitchie Manitou](http://firstpeoplesofcanada.com/fp_groups/fp_wh5.html)", and the Aztecs "[Teotl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teotl)". All three equated the name with something like "Great Mystery".

Comment: It's also very hard to pin down exactly what the spiritual beliefs north of the Rio Grande in the early 17th century were as the initial colonists had no interest at all in anthropological or theological investigations of other peoples and as pre-literate civilizations, the various tribespeople kept no records themselves.  I don't think anyone really started keeping records until the 19th century, after 200 years of contact.   We can guess that the beliefs of the Sioux were similar, but it must be born in mind that there was massive cultural change due to forced migration, etc.

Comment: @StevenBurnap - This is very, very true. For instance, I tried looking up Iroquois beliefs for this answer, but the only thing I could find well-documented is a post-contact cult that has a lot of Christian borrowings. We got *really* lucky with the (Siouxan) Osages because their own Christian-influenced movement had just taken hold when the first Anthropologists started talking with them. This meant the old beliefs were still in living memory, but were no longer held to (and thus there was no longer a taboo about delving deeply into them).